# How can i create a gnosis safe wallet from another smart contract?

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, multisignature, proxy-contracts, gnosis

I already have a factory contract that is used to deploy the logic contract but with the deployment of the logic contract I also want to create a gnosis safe wallet, So is it possible to create gnosis safe from the solidity smart contract with the required owners and the threshold?

```
contract Factory {
  constructor(..) {...}
  function deployContract (...) {
     //Deployment of logic contract
     //Deployment of the gnosis safe
  }
}
```

I already have created gnosis-safe using the gnosis-safe-SDK from the reactjs in frontend the central motive of moving the deployment of the gnosis safe from the frontend to blockchain is to reduce the number of web-3 calls on frontend.